# Transform snake_case to camelCase

Tags: python, regex

I want to convert db columns such as `is_deleted` or `product_code` which consist of `xx_xx` to java-style names: `isDeleted` or `productCode`. I wonder if there is a way to improve my following code, using regex or such things.

```
def getJavaName(column):                                                         
   words = column.split('_')                                                    
   first = words[0]                                                             
   return first + ''.join((w.capitalize() for w in words[1:]))
```

Comment: Since this is under the code review section, I'll provide the answer I would in a real code review. Don't do it at all. Doing a refactoring of naming in this way has a fair chance of introducing bugs with no improvement in functionality. AKA: If it ain't broke don't fix it. Spend the time you save working on new features or fixing real problems.

Comment: @user69264 Thanks for practical suggestions. Actually，I wrote this script  replace an  Eclipse plugin used in my work, also for purpose——leaning python :)

Comment: Actually this type of name refactoring has been going on for years in the Client-Server, SOA, and ETL spaces.  It is not so much to rename columns or alter DDL, but to create mappings of the objects as structs and such. So if I am working in C, I want the naming conventions and familiar look and feel.  This matters still as there is a lot of Java-DB2 going on. Not to mention Django.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should remove the many trailing spaces.

You can replace slicing with unpacking and the double-brackets can be removed:

```
def getJavaName(column):
   first, *rest = column.split('_')
   return first + ''.join(word.capitalize() for word in rest)
```

Python uses `snake_case`, even if your DB columns don't, so you should be calling this `get_java_name` - although personally it's still better named `snake_to_camel_case` and the `column` parameter should be renamed to, say, `name`.

Comment: I like the way you are doing the extraction. nice.

Comment: `first, *rest = column.split('_')` doesn't work in Python 2.x.

Comment: @NizamMohamed you can use   first, rest = column.split('_')[0], column.spilt('_')[1:] in Python 2.x

Comment: Thanks for this, neat little trick for manipulating the result array

Answer (score 7):

Using regex,

```
import re
def getJavaName(column):
    return re.sub('_.',lambda x: x.group()[1].upper(),column)
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider writing this as a one-liner regular expression substitution instead.

```
import re

def get_java_name(column_name):
    return re.sub('_([a-z])', lambda match: match.group(1).upper(), column_name)
```

Since the function is Python code, it should still adhere to PEP 8 naming conventions — `get_java_name()` instead of `getJavaName()`.

Comment: This fails for non-ASCII identifiers. You might argue that it's bad practice anyway, though ;).